AuthenticateAsync returns null in .NET 8 at all times
If anyone can give me a clue as to where I am going wrong. I have slowly been upgrading my code base from .NET 6 to .NET 8. With my authorization controller, in the authorize method with .NET 6 this line of code
var results = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)

would return null or not succeed. I would then hit the Login Razor Page and Sign In, the same result would then be an actual AuthenticateResult.
With the upgrade to .NET 8, it always returns null even after I sign in. I have looked with the Dev Tools open and I can see that the sign in does generate a cookie. I am testing this from Postman using the authorization tab in there and using all the correct parameters.
Here is what is not changed from .NET 6 to .NET 8:
Authorize method:
[HttpGet(Name = nameof(Authorize))]
[HttpPost(Name = nameof(Authorize))]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

    // Retrieve the user principal stored in the authentication cookie.
    // If it can't be extracted, redirect the user to the login page.
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

    if (result == null || !result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (request.HasPrompt(Prompts.None))
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.LoginRequired,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is not logged in."
                }));
        }

        return Challenge(
            authenticationSchemes: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + QueryString.Create(
                    Request.HasFormContentType ? Request.Form.ToList() : Request.Query.ToList())
            });
    }

    if (request.HasPrompt(Prompts.Login))
    {
        var prompt = string.Join(" ", request.GetPrompts().Remove(Prompts.Login));

        var parameters = Request.HasFormContentType ?
            Request.Form.Where(parameter => parameter.Key != Parameters.Prompt).ToList() :
            Request.Query.Where(parameter => parameter.Key != Parameters.Prompt).ToList();

        parameters.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(Parameters.Prompt, new StringValues(prompt)));

        return Challenge(
            authenticationSchemes: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + QueryString.Create(parameters)
            });
    }

    if (request.MaxAge != null && result.Properties.IssuedUtc != null &&
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - result.Properties.IssuedUtc > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(request.MaxAge.Value))
    {
        if (request.HasPrompt(Prompts.None))
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.LoginRequired,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is not logged in."
                }));
        }

        return Challenge(
            authenticationSchemes: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + QueryString.Create(
                    Request.HasFormContentType ? Request.Form.ToList() : Request.Query.ToList())
            });
    }

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(result.Principal) ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The user details cannot be retrieved");

    var application = await _applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(request.ClientId) ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Details concerning the calling client application cannot be found");

    var permissionsArray = await _applicationManager.GetPermissionsAsync(application);
    var scopes = permissionsArray.Where(a => a.StartsWith("scp:")).Select(a => a[4..]).ToList().ToImmutableArray();

    var authorizations = await _authorizationManager.FindAsync(
        subject: await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user),
        client: await _applicationManager.GetIdAsync(application),
        status: Statuses.Valid,
        type: AuthorizationTypes.Permanent,
        scopes: scopes).ToListAsync();

    switch (await _applicationManager.GetConsentTypeAsync(application))
    {
        case ConsentTypes.External when !authorizations.Any():
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.ConsentRequired,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] =
                    "The logged in user is not allowed to access this client."
                }));

        case ConsentTypes.Implicit:
        case ConsentTypes.External when authorizations.Any():
        case ConsentTypes.Explicit when authorizations.Any() && !request.HasPrompt(Prompts.Consent):
            var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

            principal.SetScopes(scopes);
            principal.SetResources(await _scopeManager.ListResourcesAsync(principal.GetScopes()).ToListAsync());

            var authorization = authorizations.LastOrDefault();

            if (authorization == null)
            {
                authorization = await _authorizationManager.CreateAsync(
                    principal: principal,
                    subject: await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user),
                    client: await _applicationManager.GetIdAsync(application),
                    type: AuthorizationTypes.Permanent,
                    scopes: principal.GetScopes());
            }

            principal.SetAuthorizationId(await _authorizationManager.GetIdAsync(authorization));

            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
                claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
            }

            return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        case ConsentTypes.Explicit when request.HasPrompt(Prompts.None):
        case ConsentTypes.Systematic when request.HasPrompt(Prompts.None):
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.ConsentRequired,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] =
                    "Interactive user consent is required."
                }));

        default:
            return View(new AuthorizeViewModel
            {
                ApplicationName = await _applicationManager.GetDisplayNameAsync(application),
                Scope = string.Join(" ", scopes)
            });
    }
}

Login page:
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUsers> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUsers> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        //Snipped fro brevity
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user) || (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user)))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Login was unsuccessful through controller");
                }

                if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Login was unsuccessful through controller");
                    await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                }

                if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
                }

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }

                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, Input.RememberMe });
                }

                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }
}

Here is what I have changed in the .NET 6 to .NET 8 basically a move from startup.cs to program.cs:
.NET 6 startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Policy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("Cors:Origins").GetChildren().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray())
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddDbContext<IdentDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDB"));

        options.UseOpenIddict();
    });

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<IdentDbContext>()
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
        .SetApplicationName("Applications");

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUsers, ApplicationRoles>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentDbContext>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
        .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddErrorDescriber<ApplicationIdentityErrorDescriber>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;

        // Configure the options for the Identity Account
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });

    services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    });

    services.AddQuartz(options =>
    {
        options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
        options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
        options.UseInMemoryStore();
    });

    services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

    services.AddOpenIddict()
        // Register the OpenIddict core components.
        .AddCore(options =>
        {
            options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<IdentDbContext>();

            options.UseQuartz();
        })
        // Register the OpenIddict server components.
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/api/Authorization/Authorize")
            .SetTokenEndpointUris("/Token")
            .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/Introspect")
            .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/api/Userinfo/Userinfo")
            .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/Verify");

            options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.OpenId, Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

            options.UseReferenceAccessTokens()
            .UseReferenceRefreshTokens()
            .UseDataProtection();

            options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
            .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
            .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

            if (_env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                      .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
            }
            else if (_env.IsProduction() || _env.IsStaging())
            {
                options.AddSigningCertificate(Configuration.GetSection("CertifcateThumbprints:SigningCertificate").Value)
                .AddEncryptionCertificate(Configuration.GetSection("CertifcateThumbprints:EncryptionCertificate").Value);
            }

            options.UseAspNetCore()
                   .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                   .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                   .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                   .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                   .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough();
        })
        // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
        .AddValidation(options =>
        {
            options.UseLocalServer();
            options.UseDataProtection();
            options.UseSystemNetHttp();
            options.UseAspNetCore();
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger => 
    {        
        swagger.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
        swagger.OperationFilter<AuthenticationRequirementOperationFilter>();
        swagger.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());

        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        swagger.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
    services.AddApiVersioning();
    services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVVV";
        options.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersion.Parse("0.10.alpha");
        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    });

    services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
    if (_env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
    }
    else if (_env.IsStaging() || _env.IsProduction())            
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ProdStageSeed>();
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
    if (_env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors("Policy");

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {               
        c.DisplayOperationId();
        var versionDescription = provider.ApiVersionDescriptions;
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(_ => _.ApiVersion))
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", $"API {description.GroupName}");
        }
    });

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

.NET 8 program.cs:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Policy", opt =>
    {
        opt.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Cors:Origins").GetChildren().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray()!)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EntityIdJsonConverterFactory());
    });

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDB"));

    options.UseOpenIddict();
});

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<IdentDbContext>()
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
            .SetApplicationName("Applications");

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUsers, ApplicationRoles>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentDbContext>()
    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
    .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<ApplicationIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});

builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
});

builder.Services.AddQuartz(options =>
{
    options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
    options.UseInMemoryStore();
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    // Register the OpenIddict core components.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
        .UseDbContext<IdentDbContext>();

        options.UseQuartz();
    })
    // Register the OpenIddict server components.
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("api/Authorization/Authorize")
        .SetTokenEndpointUris("Token")
        .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("Introspect")
        .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("api/Userinfo/Userinfo")
        .SetVerificationEndpointUris("Verify");

        options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.OpenId, Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

        options.UseReferenceAccessTokens()
        .UseReferenceRefreshTokens()
        .UseDataProtection();

        options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
        .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
        .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
        .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

        if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                  .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
        }
        else if (builder.Environment.IsProduction() || builder.Environment.IsStaging())
        {
            options.AddSigningCertificate(builder.Configuration.GetSection("CertifcateThumbprints:SigningCertificate").Value!)
            .AddEncryptionCertificate(builder.Configuration.GetSection("CertifcateThumbprints:EncryptionCertificate").Value!);
        }
        options.UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
               .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough();
    })
    // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();

        options.UseDataProtection();

        options.UseSystemNetHttp();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    swagger.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
    swagger.OperationFilter<AuthenticationRequirementOperationFilter>();
    swagger.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());

    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    swagger.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});

builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(0, 10, "alpha");
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
}).AddMvc()
    .AddApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = false;
    });

builder.Services.AddApplication()
    .AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration)
    .AddDataLibrary();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Login", sp => { sp.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseAddresses:Api").Value!); });

builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<ProdStageSeed>();
}
else if (builder.Environment.IsStaging() || builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<ProdStageSeed>();
}

builder.Host.UseWolverine(opts =>
{
    opts.PersistMessagesWithSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDB")!);
    opts.UseEntityFrameworkCoreTransactions();
    opts.Policies.AutoApplyTransactions();
    opts.Policies.UseDurableLocalQueues();
    opts.Discovery.IncludeAssembly(Assembly.Load("IdentityApplication"));
    opts.UseFluentValidation();

    opts.Services.AddResourceSetupOnStartup();
    opts.OnException<SqlException>().MoveToErrorQueue();
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<ExceptionMiddleware>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsStaging())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    var provider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.DisplayOperationId();
        var versionDescription = provider.ApiVersionDescriptions;
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(_ => _.ApiVersion))
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", $"API {description.GroupName}");
        }
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCors("Policy");

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

So with the minimal change I made I cannot figure out why the result is always returning null. A cookie is generated by the Login Page and does show up in program and Postman. I understand that the AuthenticateAsync changed in .NET 7 but I cannot find any good documentation as to what might be affected in my code. Not sure what the cause is, but I have been stuck on this for over a week.
